# I am writing a script to scrape a website and download files. After downloading, I am trying to rename the files and it's not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, csv, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

```
path='C:/Users/ks/Downloads/AU/ORR/'
print (path)
substring = "w"
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    src=path+file
    if substring in file:
        break
        print ("there")
    else:
        print ("not there")
        dst='Pattern_'+substring+str(org)+str(m1)+'.csv'
        dst=path+dst

    os.rename(src,dst)
```

The print statements are just for debugging. Everything is getting printed but still the rename function is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Using `break` leaves the loop for good. You probably want `continue` to skip exactly this iteration of the loop.

Your code will stop doing anything after the first time `substring` is not in `file`.

See [break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)